# Eeek! - Resin in my hair

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, hair

I have long hair and like being out in the woods. Unfortunately this means I sometimes get resin (or sap) in my hair. It's always a pain to get it out, sometimes I have no choice but cutting the "afflicted" strain of hair.

#### How can I *painlessly* remove resin from my hair without cutting it?

Ideally this would also work for clothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with it sticking in clothing which I couldn't really put in the washer.
My mothers neat trick: Put peanut-butter on it... Leave it for some time and wash it with hot water.

I hope this applies to hair as well...

Comment: No need for the peanut part though. Butter will do. Came to think about it: most likely kitchenoil should do even better.